# Tie stock quote value to cell in Excel 2011 Mac

Tags: database, macos, excel, excel-web-query

I've been working on a mock stock portfolio in Excel, and I've been looking for ways to automatically update the data, eg. stock price and P/E ratio.

I have tried using a web query to MSN Money, but that just brings up the whole stock quote across multiple cells, I want data to be updated in individual cells only. The only web query solution I can think of is if someone hosted a website where each value in the stock quote was saved on a different HTML file. I could then WebQuery to that file for each cell requiring that value. However, no website offers this.

So in essence, is there any tool on Excel 2011 Mac that will let me pull individual values from a stock quote and assign them to a single cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the following:

For each stock, create a worksheet which contains a web query to that stock's web page.

Next, create a summary sheet, from where you link to the cells on the individual stock worksheets which contain the data you need.

Then, with 'refresh all connections' your data on the summary worksheet would update.